# Automatic Page redirection not working in safari browser

Tags: php, javascript

I am using below code for automatically redirect to the page in a fraction of seconds.

```
<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
var testTimerID;

testTimerID = window.setTimeout(autoDirect, 30*250 );

function autoDirect() {
window.location = 'home';
}
</script>
```

- This script works fine in all browser except in safari browser.it does not automatically redirect to the another page(home). what is the issue?.how can i solve it?.

Comment: I guess you forgot the part of code ;).

Comment: Could You please provide the code? There is none...

Comment: You might want to add `// -->` to the end of the script or remove the `<!--`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
//<!--
var testTimerID;

testTimerID = window.setTimeout(function(){
    window.location.href = '/home';
}, 30*250 );
//-->
</script>
```

Usually JS does not work properly and in same way through all the web browsers... Therefore I advise to use jQuery as it is debugged for all common browsers...

Try aslo reading through this: [How to redirect to another webpage in JavaScript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery)

Also instead of relative URL You shoudl use absolute like `http://www.mydomain.com/home/`, so the code should be:

```
...
    window.location.href = 'http://www.mydomain.com/home/';
...
```

.

Comment: Why on earth would a simple redirect work better in jQuery than in simple javascript??? -1 for that  but +1 for the absolute or complete url

Comment: I always recommend using of jQuery instead of plain JS just cos of different JS implementation through many web browsers... While with plain JS You have to check for browser and serve appropriate JS code with jQuery You just don't have to care...

Comment: hi i have another solution 

<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="8;URL=home" />

Comment: for a setTimeout and a window.location the code is identical on all browsers. In this case I am sure @Ravi is missing to give use some information.

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly in Safari 5 for windows

```
<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
var testTimerID;

testTimerID = window.setTimeout(autoDirect, 30*250 );

function autoDirect() {
  window.location = 'http://google.com/';
}
</script>
```

Comment: I used this one now..
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="8;URL=home" />
working fine

Comment: @Ravi that is even more important to use full url in a meta refresh, which by the way do not work in my Fx 4